# Не могу понять синтаксис CSS - селекторов

Tags: html, css

По сути, селектор `.класс {}` это правильный синтаксис, он у меня всегда работал, но вот столкнулся с проблемой: хочу применить `text-decoration: none` для `a.top_menu`. Не получается. Погуглил, сказали написать `.top_menu a {text-decoration: none}`. Всё заработало... Попробовал такой синтаксис применить ко всему css, чтобы не запутаться и везде одинаково писать, но такой вариант у других селекторов с классами не сработал. В чём фишка, объясните, пожалуйста.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Flat</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
      <div class="M_logo">M</div>
      <div class="inimal_logo">inimal</div>
    </div>
    <nav class="top_menu">
      <a href="#">Products</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1680px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

div.logo {
  width: 184px;
  max-width: 184px;
  height: 61px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 164px;
  position: relative;
}

div.M_logo {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 43px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

div.inimal_logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 43px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  color: #038c8c;
}

nav.top_menu {
  font-size: 19px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 300px;
  top: 18px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.top_menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Комбинаций селекторов не так много, можно просто запомнить:

`a.top_menu` — без пробела (одновременное наличие чего-либо):

      «Все теги `a` у которых есть класс `.top_menu`»

`.top_menu a` — через пробел:

      «Все теги `a` которые находятся где-то внутри элемента с классом `top_menu`»

      На любом уровне вложенности.

`.top_menu > a`:

      «Все теги `a` непосредственно внутри `top_menu` (1-й уровень вложенности)»

`.top_menu + a`:

      «Тег `a`, который расположен сразу после `top_menu`».

      Между ними могут быть пробелы и текст, но не другие теги.

`.top_menu ~ a`:

      «Один или несколько `a`, расположенные где-то после `top_menu`»

      Между ними могут быть и другие теги, но все они - на одном уровне вложенности.

---

Справка → https://webref.ru/css#selectors

P.s. Естественно, вместо селектора тега `<a>` — там может быть название другого класса.

P.p.s. Они не обязательно должны быть только парами:

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked + .moo { color: red; }

/* class="moo", который сразу после элемента с тремя одновременными признаками:
   (без пробелов) тег - input, тип - radio, отмечен (:checked) */
```

```html
<input type="radio" checked name="x"> <span class="moo">1</span> <br>
<input type="radio" name="x"> <span class="moo">2</span> <br>
<input type="radio" name="x"> <span class="moo">3</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Селекторы работают очень просто, посмотрите на селектор `.top_menu` и посмотрите что он включает в себе, чтобы более наглядно было

Вот что включает ваш селектор в том виде в котором вы его записали:

```html
<nav class="top_menu">
  <a href="#">Products</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

чтобы понять как это работает приведу пример, если вы укажите к примеру .header a {} то селектор будет работать для всех елементов ниже уровня header то есть:

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
    <div class="M_logo">M</div>
    <div class="inimal_logo">inimal</div>
  </div>
  <nav class="top_menu">
    <a href="#">Products</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

то есть смотрите на html в этом ключе как на дерево, а селектор это уровень дерева с которого он начинает действовать для вложенных элементов ;)

ваше желание будет выглядеть так:

```css
.header a {text-decoration: none}
```

или вот так:

```css
body a {text-decoration: none}
```

тэг указывается без знаков, к примеру вас интересует верхний узел body вы так и пишите, с точкой указываются селекторы по классу, с # селекторы по айди, к примеру:

```html
<body id="body">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
      <div class="M_logo">M</div>
      <div class="inimal_logo">inimal</div>
    </div>
    <nav class="top_menu">
      <a href="#">Products</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

можно записать селектор вот так

```css
#body a {text-decoration: none}
```

теперь что касается самого выражения, ваше выражение говорит следующее, взять все элементы у которых класс указан как `top_menu` далее у всех этих веток дерева взять все элементы с тегом `<a>` и задать им свойства.