# Удалить div по id при условии

Tags: javascript

Нужно удалять div при условии, например у меня есть табы

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-description" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Описание</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-specification" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Характеристики</a></li>

    <li class=""><a href="#tab-download" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Загрузки</a></li>

    <li class=""><a href="#tab-review" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Отзывов (0)</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="123">test</div>
```

Так вот, нужно если это не дискрипшен (#tab-description) удалить div с id 123

Может как то удаление на табы привязать, но блин если страница обновится то опять появится.

Прошу помощи, ооочень, Спасибо!)

Answer (score 2):

```
let description_active = document.querySelector('.nav-tabs li.active [href="#tab-description"]');
if (!description_active) {
  let div = document.querySelector("#123");
  if (div) div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

querySelector с `.nav-tabs li.active [href="#tab-description"]` таким [селектором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172079/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81-css-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/1172088#1172088) будет искать элемент с атрибутом `href="#tab-description"`, который находятся где-то внутри `li` с классом `active`. Если не найдет - вернет `null`, который в логическом контексте будет `false`.

`!null` → `!false` → `true`

Comment: что то не получается, причем если убрать !description_active    восклицательный знак, тобишь если не, то блок удаляется, но при переходе на соседнею вкладку не возвращается. 
http://build.forcetherm.ru/index.php?route=product/product&path=97_98&product_id=137

Comment: @Евгений `div.parentNode.removeChild(div)` оно полностью удаляет блок из страницы. Если его потом нужно возвращать, используйте `div.style.display = "none";` а код, переклюающий табы, пусть ставит обратно `display = "block";`. При обработке клиов можно проверять `if (кликнутый_элемент.querySelector('[href="#tab-description"]'))`